# How to Disable drawer in fragment and back back to correct fragment

Tags: android, fragment, drawer

I have a main Activity with a Fragment layout. The drawer has 3 option:

`Fragment[1], Fragment[2], Fragment[3].`

Inside Fragment[2] and Fragment[3] is one button. This button open other fragment. Fragment[4].

I want Fragment[4] without drawer but with a back button.

This is the onClick code in Fragment[2]

```
Fragment fragment = new InstalacionesEncontradasFragment();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("key", this.instalacionesConCategorias);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
mFragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame_container, fragment, "ACTIVIDADES").commit();
```

And in Fragment[4]

onCreate method:

```
getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

But this solution doesn't work.

How to disable the drawer? Where should I implement the back button? In Fragment[2] or Fragment[3]?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. You can use :

   ```
   mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
   ```

   This will lock drawer opening on `swipe`
2. Add the line

   ```
   getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
   ```

in Activity which makes all fragments like Fragment 1, 2,3 and 4. May be in your case, Fragment 4 is from differenct activity than Fragment 2. So, back button press is not working

Comment: Where i write`mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);` Fragment[4] has not declared mDrawerLayout

Comment: Either pass the variable to `fragment4` or use it by making `static`

Comment: Thank you. `public static DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;` in main Activity is good solution. Then I instantiate it as `public DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout = Main.mDrawerLayout;` in Fragment[4]. Is it ok?

Comment: yes it is ok.. it will surve your purpose.. in Fragment[4] use it like -- `Main.mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);` like this

Comment: Thank you and i am glad about this