# How to disable navigation drawer of activity from within a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I've been looking for an answer to this for a while but I haven't found any answers on the subject.

So I have my Main Activity which containers a toolbar, a nav drawer, and a frame layout (the container for my fragments). So on the start of the activity it starts a fragment to display and I can switch between different fragments and they all have the toolbar and nav drawer because their container is still main activity.

Except there is one problem. I want to make a new fragment and I don't want it to use a nav drawer or a toolbar. I figured out how to disable and hide the toolbar from within that specific fragment but I haven't been able to find out how to disable the nav drawer. The user can still swipe from left to right to open the nav drawer. I don't want them to be able to do that.

Also if I was going to disable it, I need to disable it from the fragment not the main activity because the navigation to this fragment is from a button that's inside another fragment

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

This will lock drawer opening on `swipe`

Source : [How to Disable drawer in fragment and back back to correct fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29797075/how-to-disable-drawer-in-fragment-and-back-back-to-correct-fragment)